# Perforce (p4v) keeps crashing when connecting to specific work space

Tags: perforce, p4v

When I open perforce (and a specific workspace that I want to use) it freezes for a moment and then crashes. I've tried opening perforce with other workspaces and made new ones and they work fine. From there if I try connecting to the work space that I want the same occurs and perforce just crashes. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is it only P4V that crashes, or are you seeing the same behavior at the command line?  Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of the client app?

Comment: Only P4v crashes. Sorry I am a newb and don't know how/what to check at command line.
I have tried repairing p4V using the installer and it still crashes.

Comment: The straightforward workaround would be to use one of the other workspace you're able to create.  If you have a support contract with Perforce you should be able to send them a crash dump from P4V to have them figure out why it's crashing and patch it.  They might also be able to guide you through doing some diagnostics at the command line to figure out what's peculiar about this particular workspace.

Comment: Ok I'll try moving to a new workspace thanks